# css slider, remove unwanted space?

Tags: html, css, slider

I'm learning CSS3 and trying to create a pure CSS slider,
it worked quite well so far however, *I'm now having an unwanted padding(margin?) inside my slider*.

I have fixed it by changing the  margins, but still don't see why there is this space.

What can I do? How to solve that ?

**But more than anything else, where does this space come from?**
 (so that I fully understand how to modify it by myself)

[slider with unwanted space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymNuC.png)

[ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0sg1.jpg)

Here is the html part

```
<div class="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="hanoi.svg" alt="hanoi"height=450px width=1500px>
    <img src="saigon.jpg" alt="saigon" height=450px width=1500px>
    <img src="danang.jpg" alt="danang" height=450px width=1500px>
  </figure>
</div>
```

And that's the css

```
.slider{
width: 1500px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left:125px;
border: 5px solid #777773;
}

.slider figure{
width: 4500px;
height: 415px;
position: relative;
animation: 20s sliding infinite;
}

figure > img{
float:left;
}

@keyframes sliding{

0%{
  left:0px;
}

20%{
  left:0px;
}

40%{
  left:-1500px;
}

60%{
  left:-1500px;
}

80%{
  left:-3000px;
}

100%{
  left:-3000px;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure element has a default style.
Please reset the style.

```
figure {
  margin: 0
}
```